# Getting selected items from a SharePoint:ListViewByQuery webpart, embedded in a Visual Webpart

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I am having trouble getting the selected items from a ListViewByQuery webpart, using the Client Object Model (JavaScript).

**Code (server-side)**

```
<SharePoint:ListViewByQuery runat="server" ID="lvbqMyNews" Enabled="True" DisableSort="False" DisableFilter="False" />
```

**Code (client-side)**

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);

//returns: [] when anything is selected.
```

I've tested the same code when going to a normal List in SharePoint, where it gets the selected items perfectly.

**Problem**

I am not able to get the selected items from the Embedded ListViewByQuery webpart (User control), when I have selected from a ListViewByQuery in a Webpart where I have added the control myself.

If I attempt the same operation on a normal list, then there is no problem getting the list of items. It seems like the Client Object Model is not aware of the ListViewByQuery webpart..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your syntax for the Client Object Model might not be correct. It should be:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
```

It's `SP.ClientContext` and not `SP.Context`.

Also, you could try using the `XSLTListViewWebPart` instead of `ListViewByQuery` webpart. I have used it successfully before,  with the `SP.ListOperation` namespace.

See the following links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630941.aspx
http://benredl.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/using-the-xsltlistviewwebpart-with-a-custom-query/

Comment: May I ask if why is it possible to do this only on client side why not on the server side with c# code ???